# Prevent multiple sliders from going over a max value-Jquery Mobile Multipage template

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I just managed to build some javascript code to ensure that multiple sliders do not exceed a maximum value of 24.

The problem is that when I try and use this in a multipage template in jquery mobile, it only works for the first page and fails to check for the second page loaded via multipage template.

Here is my jsFiddle to give a better idea of the situation

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/WEewU/20/

first page works, 2nd page does not.

I am trying to ensure that any number of sliders on a page do NOT exceed 24 hours.  And then use this code across all multi-page templates in jquery mobile.

Full Code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.min.css"
    />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <!-- Home Page-->
        <div data-role="page" id="home">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="myheader">
                 <h1>test</h1>

            </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content">

                <ul id="sliders1">
                    <li>
                        <input type="range" id="slider" class="value" name="slider1" value="0"
                        min="0" max="24" data-highlight="true" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="range" class="value" id="slider" name="slider2" value="0"
                        min="0" max="24" data-highlight="true" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="range" class="value" id="slider" name="slider3" value="0"
                        min="0" max="24" data-highlight="true" />
                    </li>
                </ul> <a href="#home2">Link to 2nd page</a> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="home2">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="myheader">
                 <h1>test</h1>

            </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content">
                <ul id="sliders">
                    <li>
                        <input type="range" id="slider" class="value" name="slider4" value="0"
                        min="0" max="24" data-highlight="true" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="range" class="value" id="slider" name="slider5" value="0"
                        min="0" max="24" data-highlight="true" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="range" class="value" id="slider" name="slider6" value="0"
                        min="0" max="24" data-highlight="true" />
                    </li>
                </ul> <a href="#home">Link to Home</a> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
     var sliders = $("#sliders1 .slider");

                    sliders.each(function() {
                        var max = 24;
                        var value = Number($(this).text(), 10),
                            availableTotal = max;
                    });

                    $(".value").change(function() {
                        var thisAmount = Number($(this).prop("value"));
                        var totalMax = 24;
                        var indMin = Number($(this).attr("min"));
                        var indMax = Number($(this).attr("max"));
                        var total = 0;

                        //Get the values of all other text boxes
                        $('.value').not(this).each(function() {
                            total += Number($(this).prop("value"));
                        });

                        //Find the remaining from our total sliders max
                        var remaining = totalMax - total;

                        if (remaining < 0) {
                            remaining = 0;
                        }
                        //if we are under our minimums, go for it! Otherwise, reduce the number.
                        if (thisAmount >= indMin && thisAmount < indMax && thisAmount < totalMax && thisAmount < remaining) {
                            $(this).siblings(".slider").slider("option", "value", thisAmount);
                            //total += thisAmount;
                        } else {
                            //var setMax = ((indMax + totalMax) - Math.abs(indMax - totalMax)) / 2;
                            var setMax = Math.min(indMax, totalMax, remaining);
                            $(this).siblings(".slider").slider("option", "value", setMax);
                            $(this).prop("value", setMax);
                            //total += (thisAmount - setMax);
                        }

                        //above was getting buggy, so lets just reset total and get it again
                        total = 0;
                        //Get the values of all text boxes
                        $('.value').each(function() {
                            total += Number($(this).prop("value"));
                        });
                        //Find our new remaining number after updating total for this value
                        remaining = totalMax - total;
                        if (remaining < 0) {
                            remaining = 0;
                        }
                        //Set each slider to the current point and update their max values.
                        $('.value').each(function() {
                            var sliderVal = Number($(this).prop("value"));
                            var sliderMin = Number($(this).attr("min"));
                            var sliderMax = Number($(this).attr("max"));
                            var setNewMax = (((sliderMax + totalMax) - Math.abs(sliderMax - totalMax)) / 2);
                            var newMax = sliderVal + remaining;

                            if (newMax < setNewMax) {
                                $(this).siblings('.slider').slider("option", "max", newMax);
                            } else {
                                $(this).siblings('.slider').slider("option", "max", setNewMax);
                            }
                            $(this).prop("max", setNewMax);
                        });
                    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`jQuery Mobile`** has a beautiful thing called page events. They will execute on a specific page or on a number of pages and they work only with **`jQuery Mobile`** so count them as specific events. To find more about there take a look at this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**, to be more transparent this is my personal blog. Or find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**.

This is a working example of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/e8xZ2/

Lets go through changes:

1. At a top left corner jQuery 1.8.3 is selected and changed to *`*onDomReady`**
2. jQuery code is initialized with a :

   ```
   $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#home, #home2', function(){
   ```

   It will make sure that this code is executed on a pages with id **home** and **homn2**.
3. Sliders and input boxes are accessed through a **`$.mobile.activePage`**. Basically this is an active page **`jQuery Mobile`** selector.

   ```
   $.mobile.activePage.find("#sliders1 .slider");
   ```

   and

   ```
   $.mobile.activePage.find('.value').not(this).each(function() {
   ```
4. Your **`jQuery Mobile`** framework is upgraded to stable 1.2 version

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't realize that jquery mobile had an active page find for sliders and input boxes.  Makes a lot more sense.